# Spring-boot fails to build a project - an attempt was made to call a method that does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I found similar problems, but I can not figure out what is my problem with building the project?
I am just new with Maven configurations and Spring boot.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>group.project.sixteen</groupId>
    <artifactId>cs2001-2021_22-group16_2021</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

When I try to run one java class (Only one in the java src)

```
package group.project.sixteen.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GroupProjectApplicationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GroupProjectApplicationMain.class, args);
    }
}
```

It gives me this problem:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.3)

2022-02-15 21:07:04.681 ERROR 11316 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:300)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext.setApplicationStartup(org.springframework.core.metrics.ApplicationStartup)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.6.3/spring-boot-2.6.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd/IdeaProjects/cs2001-2021_22-group16_2021/lib/spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.3.15/spring-context-5.3.15.jar!/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext: file:/C:/Users/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%83%d1%85%d0%b0%d0%bd/IdeaProjects/cs2001-2021_22-group16_2021/lib/spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication and org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think the problem is from project configuration. Cause, this is my branch from the GitHub project and I just deleted most of the 80% HTML, CSS, js files and left 4 files to work with on the back-end.

How can I deal with this problem?
And once I finish my code, can my groupmates just clone my branch and run without problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Do not use windows :D

Comment: How are you running spring boot?

Comment: I am running on IntelliJ IDEA -> run an application.